# Cement holding tank

Tags: plumbing, water, water-damage, septic

I have a new 1000 gallon cement holding tank with no plumbing or drains hooked up yet I went to the property today and it is completely full of water. Is it broken? Thanks for any help.

Comment: why would you think that a holding tank, that actually holds water, is somehow broken?

Comment: what is the purpose of the tank?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As a holding tank, it's hardly broken - it's doing its job admirably! It's probably *concrete* rather than cement, though. Why would anyone one to keep cement in a tank..?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty normal. My septic tank filled up long before plumbing was attached to it. Water (groundwater, rainwater) comes in through the not-particularly well sealed joints around top openings/manholes, and then it's in the tank.

Comment: I have water level sensors on my holding tank to monitor the pump and water levels, and despite my best effort to seal the tank, I can see that ground water still finds a way in.